# Run jQuery slider script using AJAX

Tags: jquery, ajax, slider

I'm trying to run jQuery slider script using AJAX with no luck.

Here is the AJAX call:

**HTML**

```
 <div id="sn"><a href="#" id="button" onclick="loadDoc('sn','example4.html')">test</a></div>
```

**JS**

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
function loadDoc(id, url) {
  if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
    // code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari 
    xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
  } else {
    // code for IE6, IE5 
    xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP"); 
  } 
  xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200) {
      document.getElementById(id).innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
    }
  } 
  xmlhttp.open("GET",url,false); 
  xmlhttp.send(null);
} 
</script>
```

Here is where I implement the jQuery slider script :

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
 <html lang="en">
 <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css" />
 </head>
 <body>
    <div class="container">
        <div id="va-accordion" class="va-container">
            <div class="va-nav">
                <span class="va-nav-prev">Previous</span>
                <span class="va-nav-next">Next</span>
            </div>
            <div class="va-wrapper" style="background:#f9e830;">
                <div class="va-slice va-slice-1">
                    <div class="va-content">
                        <p>TEST1</p>

                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="va-slice va-slice-2">
                    <div class="va-content">
                        <p>TEST2</p>

                    </div>  
                </div>
                <div class="va-slice va-slice-3">
                    <div class="va-content">
                        <p>TEST3</p>

                    </div>  
                </div>

                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

    </div>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.easing.1.3.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.mousewheel.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.vaccordion.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function() {
            $('#va-accordion').vaccordion({
                expandedHeight  : 350,
                animSpeed       : 400,
                animOpacity     : 0.7,
                visibleSlices   : 2
            });
        });
    </script>
</body>
```

And here is CSS for slider

```
 /* Vertical Accordion Style */
.va-container{
position:relative;
margin:40px auto 0 auto;
 }
.va-wrapper{
width:100%;
height:100%;
position:relative;
overflow:hidden;
background:#000;
 }
.va-slice{
cursor:pointer;
position:absolute;
width:100%;
left:0px;
overflow:hidden;
 }

.va-title{
font-family: 'Open Sans Condensed', sans-serif;
text-transform:uppercase;
font-size:60px;
margin-left:20px;
color:#fff;
text-shadow: 0px 0px 1px white;
 }
 .va-content{
display:none;
margin-left:25px;
 }
 .va-slice p{
font-size: 22px;
font-style: italic;
font-family:Georgia, serif;
 }
 .va-slice ul{
margin-top:20px;
 }
 .va-slice ul li{
float:left;
margin:0px 2px;
 }
 .va-slice ul li a{
color:#000;
background:#eede2f;
padding:3px 6px;
font-size:14px;
font-family:'PT Sans', sans-serif;
text-transform:uppercase;
}
.va-slice ul li a:hover{
background:#000;
color:#fff;
text-shadow:none;
}
.va-nav span{
width:40px;
height:25px;
background:transparent url(../images/prev.png) no-repeat center center;
position:absolute;
top:-35px;
left:50%;
margin-left:-20px;
text-indent:-9000px;
opacity:0.7;
cursor:pointer;
display:none;
z-index:100;
 }
 .va-nav span.va-nav-next{
background-image:url(../images/next.png);
top:auto;
bottom:-35px;
 }
.va-nav span:hover{
opacity:1.0;
 }
```

So everything works fine, if it's not running from AJAX. 
Any ideas how to make all these work ?
Thanks )

SOLUTION :

```
 <div id="sn"><a href="#" id="button" onclick="loadDoc('sn','example4.html');jQuery('#va-accordion').vaccordion();">test</a></div>
```

Comment: OK, you say "Here is usual AJAX line" but I've never heard of `loadDoc`. Did you write that function? What's the code? What is that link supposed to do? What is your program supposed to do? Why have you posted minimal JQuery code for a JQuery question? Have you looked at JSFiddle? Sorry, welcome to StackOverflow.

Comment: loadDoc also usual ) That's why didn't post it.<script type="text/javascript">
function loadDoc(id, url)
{
if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
  {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
  xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
  }
else
  {// code for IE6, IE5
  xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
  }
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
  {
  if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
    {
    document.getElementById(id).innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
    }
  }
xmlhttp.open("GET",url,false);
xmlhttp.send(null);
}
</script>

Comment: Sorry man, but replies to your questions are obvious. "What is your program supposed to do?" - this is a slider.What do you think slider can do? It slides )) Read the code please. It's simple.

Comment: But you didn't state what was wrong. You threw up a block of irrelevant code, `loadDoc` isn't "usual", much less written in jQuery like you tagged. "It's not working" isn't going to get you anywhere here. Does the page not render? Does your AJAX request fail? Do panthers eat your children? "The whole output" doesn't mean anything either. Your question is unclear and lacks explanation. So "Read the code, please. It's simple" doesn't begin to explain what you're asking

Comment: @JohnK this is a slider: http://jqueryui.com/demos/slider/ not what you think is a slider. if you're going to ask for help you should be more specific. you should ditch most of `loadDoc` and look at using this: http://api.jquery.com/load/. you probably have a syntax error too since there are two `</div>`s at the same indentation level near the end. i'd go and make a demo for you but i don't really like your attitude so you're on your own.

Comment: @Kyle Macey I'm not here to discuss with you what is usual and what is not.I think this is a simple code and any advanced coder can read it easy without the additional comments.

Comment: @Joe Flateau I don't like your attitude either.It doesn't mean, that I'm baby in coding, if I'm asking help.Load function works fine.And two </div>s can't cause anything since the slider by itself is working.

Comment: @JohnK So what's wrong? What happens when you include your AJAX link (Wherever you're putting that)? This is really the prime part we're all looking for, here. What do you see? Can we see your problem hosted somewhere? Again, I bring up JSFiddle.

Comment: I wrote already.It shows nothing while the AJAX button is clicked.However, if .va-slice{position:absolute;} is changed to relative it shows all <div>s in one block (not sliced). Without the AJAX .va-slice{position:absolute;} works as it should.

Comment: Do you get anything in an error console? And your code definitely shows an extra `</div>` tag. Get that out of there if that's your actual code. This doesn't sound like a CSS issue per se, but definitely let me know if anything is in the console.

Comment: As an editing member, I owe a responsibility to the SO community to keep questions clear and understandable for other members. The only benefit is that we all scratch each other's backs.

Comment: extra </div> is a mistyping while I copied the code. re "CSS issue" But why it shows all <div>s in one,if CSS I mentioned above is changed to relative ?

Comment: @JohnK What exactly did  I delete? I can't delete posts with my rep. And can we get back to your question? Was anything in the console for your code? And have you tried setting hard dimensions for your absolute positioned DIVs?

Comment: Sorry,but one comment appeared to be deleted.No offense.Well,back to the question...Hard dimensions don't help.Re console - there is no error,as far as I understand.It just doesn't show it obviously because of CSS.And I really can't understand why ...

Answer (score 0):

Try using the load function in jQuery that's built in to handle AJAX requests like the one you wrote... We'll start by process of elimination.

Convert this:

```
<div id="sn"><a href="#" id="button" onclick="loadDoc('sn','example4.html')">test</a></div>
```

to this:

**HTML**

```
<div id="sn"><a href="#">test</a></div>
```

**JS**

```
$(function() {
  $('#sn a').on('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $('#sn').load('example4.html');
  });
});
```

**EDIT**

If it still doesn't work, and you're not seeing anything in your console, modify slightly....

```
try {
  $(function() {
    $('#sn a').on('click', function(e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      $('#sn').load('example4.html');
    });
  });
} catch(err) {
  alert(err);
}
```

Comment: My theory is something is broken in the ajax call that is stopping propagation of Javascript.

Comment: It seems to me too...Trying your suggestion...Tks)

Comment: Don't have enough jQuery knowledge to handle this.Probably will be easy to do like this: how is it possible to load this script http://tympanus.net/codrops/2011/07/22/vertical-sliding-accordion/ using AJAX load function ? In fact don't want you to waste your time here, if this is a time consuming.Thanks anyway)

Comment: Such as loading the content of each pane when the pane is opened? There is built in functionality for that in the JQUI version http://jqueryui.com/demos/accordion/

Comment: Got it ) Should be onclick="loadDoc('sn','example.html');jQuery('#va-accordion').vaccordion();" Thanks a lot.You really helped me)

Comment: Always glad to acknowledge my mistake in such cases )